# Why doesn't it print Armstrong numbers up to 1000?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, math, printing

It was working without the nested loop just to check if the input number was Armstrong number.

```
c=0
for y in range(1000):
    for x in str(y):
        c += int(x) ** len(str(y))
        if c == y:
            print(c)
```

Comment: Your real problem is that variable c must be cleaned in each iteration

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the variable `c` must be cleaned in each iteration:

```
for y in range(1000):
    c=0
    for x in str(y):
        c += int(x) ** len(str(y))
        if c == y:
            print(c)
```

Or you can use a variant like the one in @CDJB:

```
for y in range(1000):
    if sum(int(x)**len(str(y)) for x in str(y)) == y:
        print(y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because Armstrong numbers are numbers such that the sum of the cubes of each digit of the number is equal to the original number. Your code seems to be raising each digit to the nth power, where n is equal to the number of digits in the number. The below code will print Armstrong numbers less than 1000:

```
for y in range(1000):
    if sum(int(x)**3 for x in str(y)) == y:
        print(y)
```

**Output:**

```
0
1
153
370
371
407
```

From the comments, it seems there are multiple definitions of Armstrong numbers; if you seek the other definition then see @Mandy007's answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```python
for num in range(1, 1000):
    # we store total number of digit of 'num' in 'dgtLen'
    # so all individual digit of 'num' get power by 'dgtLen'
    dgtLen, sums, temp = len(str(num)), 0, num
    while temp > 0:
        sums += (temp % 10) ** dgtLen
        temp //= 10
        
    # because of this condition, we need unmodified original 'num'
    # so we store num into 'temp' & modify 'temp' instead of 'num'
    if num == sums: 
        print(num)
```

Comment: While the may work, the code seems difficult to comprehend due the choice of formatting.  I would recommend taking a look at this: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/